# JSONArray, not all data are

Tags: android, json, arrays

See if I can help. android have this code:

```
String data;
        data=httpGetData("http://192.168.1.15/CodigoPHP/prueba/consultarUsuario.php");
        if(data.length()>1)
            ja=new JSONArray(data);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "esto da:"+data,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error recuperando la informacion del servidor, verifique su conexion a internet y vuelva a intentarlo.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    try{

        for(int i=1; i<ja.length();i++) {
            british.add(ja.getString(i));
        }

        //texto.setText(ja.getString(1));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "esto da:"+ja.length(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The problem is as follows: 
Suppose there are two in my base discharged clients, and each client has eight fields. As many fields are filled 16. 
By displaying the string "data" shows me data from two clients. 
But in the JSONArray "ja" there is only one client. Show size in toast and gives me 8 Also put my JSONArray in arrayList and the same, just a client. 
And I do not understand that, and I should get it all to do 
"ja = new JSONArray (data);" 
There any explanation?

Comment: `for(int i=1; i<ja.length();i++)` - probably you want `int i = 0` here to start from the first element of the array. if doesn't help, show your json

Comment: True, it is right "int i = 0". But this does not fix the problem that I have. As I say, the variable "data" contains information from two customers, but to pass the JSONArray, it only contains a client. I show and show me what I say. 
I wonder if that's the problem of being a JSONArray. It should be a JSONObject, to enter all the customers?

Comment: show your json, please

Comment: this is String "data":
["1","xxxxxxxxxxxx","Oasis","WonderWall","http:\/\/i58.tinypic.com\/143niuf.png","Concierto de Oasis, 12 de septiembre, Madrid, Palacio deportes de la Comunidad, 21:00 h, entradas desde 40 euros en ServiCaixa.","40.4167754","-3.7037901999999576"]["2","hxxxxxxxxxxx","TAke-That","Love-Love","http:\/\/i60.tinypic.com\/2upwykh.png","Concierto de Take-That, 23 de Junio, Barcelona, Teatro Real, 22:00 h, entradas desde 50 euros en Fnac.","41.3850639","2.1734034999999494"]

Comment: this is "ja":
["1","xxxxxxxxxxxx","Oasis","WonderWall","http:\/\/i58.tinypic.com\/143niuf.png","Concierto de Oasis, 12 de septiembre, Madrid, Palacio deportes de la Comunidad, 21:00 h, entradas desde 40 euros en ServiCaixa.","40.4167754","-3.7037901999999576"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing this issue because your JSON is not valid. Array `["2",...]` is not a part of "data" object. It's represented as a separate entity.

You should change your json to something like:

```
{
  "data":[
    ["1", "value2", "value3", "value4"],
    ["2", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
  ]
}
```

Moreover, the structure itself is not good. As I see, you're using the first element of the array as index. It's better to use explicit array object index instead, and format your data not as array of arrays, but array of objects:

```
{
  "data":[
    {"name1":"value1", "name2":"value2", "name3":"value3"},
    {"name1":"value1", "name2":"value2", "name3":"value3"}
  ]
}
```

There's also a good resouce which could help you to check if String is a valid JSON object: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: but the problem is that I did not create the JSON, I created the database. The JSON httpgetdata this comes from. the problem may be that the database created this evil?

Comment: do not understand why my JSON generates bad, if I am creating a database.